# Clear data session Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm developing a Grails app, and I want to clear data or cookies when I close the session. I'm using spring security. The main goal it's that when a user leaves the session, if back button in the browser is clicked the page shows error or something.

Comment: What error is being shown?

Comment: Spring Security Plugin should do this automatically for you - that is redirect user to login page if requested resource is protected (that user does not have right to see it) - when user is not logged in

Comment: Exactly tokse, but I'm my app when I close the admin session the login page is shown, but when I click the back button in browser I can see the admin page, I can't do anything but the page stills here

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Spring Security. The page might be cached by the browser and is not loaded again if you hit the back button.

Comment: Yeah micha, but how can I do it?